# function fails if element is selected through jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, resize, textarea

I have got this code to resize a `textarea` while the user inputs data:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    let button = "#single_p_submit_btn";

    let text_area = document.querySelector('.my-singlep-form-txtarea');

    $(text_area).keydown(function () {

        $(button).removeClass('my-singlep-btn').addClass('my-singlep-btn-active');

        while ($(text_area).outerHeight() < text_area.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(text_area).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(text_area).css("borderBottomWidth"))

            && $(text_area).outerHeight() < 81

            ) {

            $(text_area).height($(text_area).height() + 1);
        }

    });

});
```

if I change this `let text_area = document.querySelector('.my-singlep-form-txtarea');` to this: `let text_area = $('.my-singlep-form-txtarea');`

The function stops working. No resize takes place. What am I missing here? The `textarea` is like this:

```
<textarea id="text_{{$post->id}}" name="single_p_text" class="my-singlep-form-txtarea" required="required" placeholder="Enter comment here" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" ></textarea>
```

Comment: wait I don't need the binding... I'll change the code

Comment: @Taplar modified the code to remove the binding.

Comment: Does the logic continue to not work?

Comment: @Taplar yes, doesn't work, maybe I need to select textarea differently through jquery? like form: input.textarea or something?

Comment: So this is a fairly good example of a case where jumping back and forth between jQuery and non-jQuery logic causes problems.  If you are going to use jQuery, use it to select the element.  That will prevent you from having to do `$(text_area)` repeatedly.  At that point you will just have to make sure you are not trying to reference Element properties directly, such as with `text_area.scrollHeight`.  If `text_area` is changed to a jQuery object, that would need to change to `text_area.prop('scrollHeight')`

Comment: ok I get it, let me try

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thanks